# Is there a reason why you shouldn't mix ssh and smart http access with git?

Tags: git, gitolite, git-remote

I have set up a git server using gitolite for a small team. One of us created a repo and pushed the initial commits using smart http - let's say it resides at

```
http://ourhost/project.git
```

I then proceeded to clone the project using ssh i.e.

```
git clone git@ourhost:project.git
```

Git let me do it and created the project folder but reported that the repo was **empty**. 
Furthermore any git pull I did gave me "**couldn't find remote ref master**" errors.
When I then ran

```
git remote -v show origin
```

It showed HEAD branch: (unknown). When I checked on the server (runs gitlab) I could see the master branch and all the code so it was clearly there.

Finally I cloned it using smart http and lo and behold it all worked and I can get on with it.

But why is this? Why should it matter which method each of us use to push/pull? Gitlab even shows the two URLs (for ssh or smart http) as alternatives for repos so it seems to be expected to work...)

Or am I missing something...?

Comment: Which version of GitLab are you running? GitLab 5.x doesn't use Gitolite anymore. Which version of Gitolite are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4...perhaps I should upgrade, do you think this issue could have been related to me using an older version?

Comment: And gitolite is version 3.2

Comment: V5 wno't have an issue with Gitolite. As for V4, I fear that using smart http, you are simply bypassing gitolite entirely.

Comment: I see, ok - so what you are saying is that you need to just pick one method and stick with it (at least for these version). We can do that - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GitLab V4, and Gitolite, ssh remains the prefered method of access.
Https access could bypass completely Gitolite.

Since [GitLab V5 doesn't use Gitolite anymore](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-5-dot-0-has-been-released/) (but now uses [**`gitlab-shell`**](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell) instead), both ssh and https access can be used more consistently with the access right management.

Comment: FYI: I've upgraded to 5.0 now and can confirm that it happily works with both git@ and http access. Thanks again!